# how to store a certain set of integer value in C++

Tags: c++, vector, integer, storage

actually I am working with tensor storage which dimension is 6187*25*78*33 . Now I am trying to store this integer value in to a vector but unfortunately after a certain period the codeblocks show a message that is std::bad_alloc. Now my question is how can I solve this problem? Is there any solution?here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

ofstream bcrs_tensor;
bcrs_tensor.open("bcrs_tensor_Binary", ios::out | ios::binary);

int X,Y,Z,M;
printf("Enter size of 1st dimension X= ");
scanf("%d",&X);
printf("\n Enter size of 2nd dimension Y= ");
scanf("%d",&Y);
printf("\n Enter size of 3rd dimension Z= ");
scanf("%d",&Z);
printf("\n Enter size of 4th dimension M= ");
scanf("%d",&M);
printf("\n");


int new_dimension_1,new_dimension_2,new_x_1,new_x_2;
new_dimension_1=X*Z;
new_dimension_2=Y*M;

int* new_A = new int[ new_dimension_1*new_dimension_2 ];
/*  // filup tensor with zero
for(int i =0; i<new_dimension_1; i++){
for(int j= 0; j< new_dimension_2; j++){
*(new_A + i*new_dimension_2 + j)=0;
}
}
*/
//read tensor value from file
ifstream read_tensor("Chicago_fourToTwo_d.txt");
int row,col,val;
if(read_tensor.is_open()){
while(read_tensor >> row >> col >> val){
*(new_A + row*new_dimension_2 + col)=val;
}
}

int x,block_ROW,block_COL;

for(x=11; x<=new_dimension_1;x++ ){
if(new_dimension_1%x == 0){
block_ROW=x;
printf("block ROW %d\n",block_ROW);
break;
}
}
for(x=13; x<=new_dimension_2;x++ ){
if(new_dimension_2%x == 0){
block_COL=x;
printf("block COL %d\n",block_COL);
break;
}
}
cout<<"here"<<endl;
int a,b,c,d,e,f,non_zero;
vector<int> block_value,CO_BCRS,RO_BCRS;
int NZB=0;
RO_BCRS.push_back(0);
for(a=0; a<new_dimension_1; a=a+block_ROW){
for(b=0; b<new_dimension_2; b=b+block_COL){
non_zero=0;
for(c=a; c<a+block_ROW; c++){
for(d=b; d<b+block_COL; d++){
printf("[%d][%d]\n",c,d);

if(*(new_A + c*new_dimension_2 + d)!=0){
non_zero++;
}
}
}
if(non_zero!=0){
for(e=a; e<a+block_ROW; e++){
for(f=b; f<b+block_COL; f++){
block_value.push_back(*(new_A + e*new_dimension_2 + f));
}
}
CO_BCRS.push_back(b);
NZB++;
}

}
RO_BCRS.push_back(NZB);
}


cout<<"Block value"<<endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator itr=block_value.begin();itr!=block_value.end();++itr){
cout<< " " << *itr ;
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"CO_BCRS"<<endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator itr=CO_BCRS.begin();itr!=CO_BCRS.end();++itr){
cout<< " " << *itr ;
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"RO_BCRS"<<endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator itr=RO_BCRS.begin();itr!=RO_BCRS.end();++itr){
cout<< " " << *itr ;
}
cout<<endl;


//block_value
int block_value_S=block_value.size();
cout<<"block_value_S "<< block_value_S <<endl;
int block_value_val;
for(int i=0; i<block_value_S;i++){
block_value_val = block_value[i];
bcrs_tensor.write((char *) &block_value_val, sizeof(int));
}
//CO_BCRS
int CO_BCRS_S=CO_BCRS.size();
cout<<"CO_BCRS_S "<< CO_BCRS_S <<endl;
int CO_BCRS_val;
for(int i=0; i<CO_BCRS_S;i++){
CO_BCRS_val = CO_BCRS[i];
bcrs_tensor.write((char *) &CO_BCRS_val, sizeof(int));
}
//RO_BCRS
int RO_BCRS_S=RO_BCRS.size();
cout<<"RO_BCRS_S "<< RO_BCRS_S <<endl;
int RO_BCRS_val;
for(int i=0; i<RO_BCRS_S;i++){
RO_BCRS_val = RO_BCRS[i];
bcrs_tensor.write((char *) &RO_BCRS_val, sizeof(int));
}

bcrs_tensor.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: its not about the integer value but rather the number of integers you want to store

Comment: My guess is you run out of ram pretty fast. So the solution here would probably be to save old values to disk and only keep those you need in ram.

Comment: You can never store "unlimited" data since you will never have unlimited memory. If you don't have enough memory (RAM), the basic options are its upgrade, using a different computer, or storing data to some other storage (disk/database/cloud/...). Also, you can check whether there is an option to store data more efficiently (for instance, is your tensor sparse?).

Comment: Can you please post your current code to allow easy reproduction of the issue

Comment: thank you for your interaction. but problem is I read the tensor value from a txt file into a dynamic array. then I declared 3 vector. that will take the value by pushback function. but after some iteration this bad alloc message show me.

Comment: Buy a machine with more RAM :-) Much more RAM. Or think of a different algorithm. Or run your program on a distributed cluster.

Comment: What is the maximum value of your integers? Note: with `int`, you need at least 8.17GB

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical limit for size of a vector is given by `std::vector::max_size()`. However, this value just takes into account limitations of the implementation. Much sooner you will run out of memory.

Vectors typically increase their capacity by factors of `2` (`3` or other factors can be used as well). Hence if you call `push_back` N-times, the memory footprint can be as big as `2*N`. And as vectors store their elements in contiguous memory, you might get a `bad_alloc` on reallocation, even though you still have enough memory for the elements you want to store. You can ask for only the capacity you actually need by calling `std::vector::reserve`.

Other than that you cannot keep more in memory than you have memory. So you basically have only two options: Get more ram or find a way to store less elements in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tensor of `61872578 * 33` `int` values, then on most architectures you need `61872578*33*4` bytes to store it - that's 7.6 GB of RAM just for one tensor.

You have four choices:

0. Change your requirements so that you no longer need a tensor that big.
1. Install enough RAM to store, manipulate, and reallocate all this in memory.
2. Set up a swap partition or a swap file with enough capacity so that the operating system will be able to put parts of the tensor on the disk. Unless your algorithms traverse the data more-or-less sequentially (or chunks of millions of sequential elements at a time) this will be unreasonably slow. This may be so slow that you may think your computer or your program stuck.
3. Rewrite your algorithm, so that it will work on parts of your tensor at a time:

   - If you want to run a convolution for a CNN then you can create a sliding window of K rows (assuming the height of your weights-tensor is K), and get rid of an old row right before reading a new one. You will have to write the result tensor as you go instead of having it all in RAM. A similar approach will work with pooling.
   - If you want to multiply your tensor by another one then break up your tensor into many smaller tensors, then do the multiplication on the smaller tensors. You can find a rough idea at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix .
   - Adding two tensors requires almost no data to be stored in RAM, just sequentially read the numbers from both tensors, add them up, and immediately store the result to disk. The lower layers (C library and OS) will employ reasonable buffering in order to make this run OK.

Note that options 2 and 3 are acceptable only if a runtime of minutes is acceptable. If you want sub-second performance then only options 0 and 1 are relevant. I may be overly pessimistic regarding to the speed of option 3 - your millage may vary depending on the throughput of your disk (mostly for option 3) and/or its latency (possibly option 2).